# Which python function would help me to extract only a line of output from a long paragraph of output?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Recently i have been trying out python to help me run Mac Terminal commands from a Python File, in particular trying to see if Bluetooth on my device is switched on or off. Below is the code i have been using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess

p = subprocess.run('sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth ', shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
print(p.stdout, p.stderr)
```

However, what usually happens is that i receive back a long output such as below:

```
{
    BluetoothAccStatus = 0;
    BluetoothVersionNumber = 6;
    ControllerPowerState = 1;
    "D2D MAC Address" = {length = 6, bytes = 0x0200693eab66};
    PersistentPorts =     {
        "incoming port - Bluetooth-Incoming-Port" =         {
            BTAuthenticationRequired = 0;
            BTEncryptionType = 0;
            BTName = "incoming port - Bluetooth-Incoming-Port";
            BTPSM = 3;
            BTRFCOMMChannel = 3;
            BTSerialConnectionType = 0;
            BTTTYName = "Bluetooth-Incoming-Port";
            HiddenPort = 1;
            IOTTYBaseName = "Bluetooth-Incoming-Port";
            P49SerialPort = 1;
        };
    };
```

However, i intend to only get the first 2 lines within that output, which are *BluetoothAccStatus* (which checks whether Bluetooth is switched on or off on my machine) and *BluetoothVersionNumber* (which confusingly shows the LMP Version of Bluetooth i have installed).

Is there a function that could reliably do the job?

Comment: You just parse `p.stdout`? Taken into account the opening brace, you just need to read the second and third line of the output (split the output by the newline character to get the individual lines).

Comment: Or you can change the actual command line command, using grep with a pipe: `sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth | grep BluetoothAccStatus`, for example. That will limit your output to just that line.

Comment: There may even be a `defaults read` option to read just one setting; you'd have to look up if that's possible.

Comment: On Mac, the grep command differs a bit if want to match multiple patterns, you might want to use: `sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth | grep -E "BluetoothAccStatus|BluetoothVersionNumber"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this some line of code or this function where you input your total paragraph and how many lines you wanna get as an output.

```
s1="Python was invented by Guido van Rossum. Python is a object oriented programming 
language. Python has over 100 of libraries."
s2=''
n=int(input("How many lines you wanna get?\n"))
i=0
for j in s1:
    if j!='.':
        s2+=j
    else:
        s2+='.'
        i+=1
    if i==n:
        break
print(s2)
```

output:
How many lines you wanna get?

1

Python was invented by Guido van Rossum.